# How to render a custom datetime format using the 'GridViewColumnsGenerator' in ASP.NET WebForms

Tags: asp.net, datetime, gridview, webforms, edit

I have a (somewhat customized) class that inherits from the ASP.NET WebForms `GridView` Control. Among other things, it should display a `DateTime` column, and allow for editing that value too. Currently, all fields are auto-generated, and for simplicity I would like to keep that this way.

However, I have a hard time to keep the datetime values correctly when doing edit roundtrips. **The control's default rendering/parsing messes up the month and day order, then stores back wrong values in the database.** I guess this has to do with some mismatch of locales between browser, IIS and Database. However, this should never be a problem IMHO.

Now, as a solution, I want to explicitly serialize/deserialize the datetime value into the well-known [ISO 8601 Data elements and interchange formats – Information interchange – Representation of dates and times](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). They use formats like "2007-04-06T00:00" for example.

I guess, I have to write a custom implementation of a `GridViewColumnsGenerator`. The [MSDN documentation on `GridViewColumnsGenerator` is pretty thin](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewcolumnsgenerator(v=vs.110).aspx), and I have not found an example somewhere so far.

**So, where to drill into `GridViewColumnsGenerator` to simply change the string representation?**

Note: I need to have edit functionality too, so just changing the text of the GridView Cell does not help.

Update: Since I have been asked, here is a (somewhat simplified) code snippet. It's really straight forward. I have a class `TableDataGridView` that derives from GridView:

Here's my code (in .aspx):

```
<myControls:TableDataGridView
    ID="TableDataGridView"
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceTableData"      
    AutoGenerateColumns="True"
    ShowHeader="True"
    ShowFooter="True"
    AutoGenerateEditButton="True"
    AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True"
    runat="server">
</myControls:TableDataGridView>
```

(in .cs):

```
[ToolboxData("<{0}:LinkTableDataGridView runat=server></{0}:LinkTableDataGridView>")]
public class TableDataGridView : GridView
{
   //...
```

Comment: Code sample??  Date/time editing, storage, serialization and deserialization have been around a long, long time.  Having to write a custom handler is likely not necessary.  Likewise passing datetime to/from a database has really become simplistic as long as you use Datetime objects.  if you are passing strings then things can get wonky.  Hard to know until we can see some of your code.

Comment: I think a better approach is to create a classed based on BoundField and generate the template yourself.